# How to get a smooth scroll in a listview with image and data

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll

I have a listview that displays some data with a image for each row. The fact is that when I scroll the listview it freezes not scrolling smooth. My code is the following:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    final int posicion = position;
    final float latitud;
    final float longitud;

    final ParkingClass parkingItems = mListParkings.get(position);

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listado_parking, null);

        //configure view holder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imgBtnBorrarItem = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnBorrarItem);
        viewHolder.imageButtonFotoHolder = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fotoParking);
        viewHolder.imgBtnNotasItem = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnNotasItem);
        viewHolder.imgBtnRuta = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnRuta);
        //viewHolder.path = parkingItems.getFoto();
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (parkingItems.getFoto() != null)
    {
        if (parkingItems.getFoto() != "NF")
        {
            Bitmap bitmap;
            bitmap = ImageHelper.decodeFile(parkingItems.getFoto());
            viewHolder.imageButtonFotoHolder.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder.imageButtonFotoHolder.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_photo_icon96));
            viewHolder.imageButtonFotoHolder.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        }
    }

    TextView txtCiudad = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCiudad);
    txtCiudad.setText(parkingItems.getCiudad());
    TextView txtCalle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCalle);
    txtCalle.setText(parkingItems.getCalle());
    TextView txtNum = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFecha);
    txtNum.setText(parkingItems.getFecha().toString());

    if (parkingItems.getLatitud() != null)
        latitud = parkingItems.getLatitud();
    else
        latitud = 0.0f;

    if (parkingItems.getLongitud() != null)
        longitud = parkingItems.getLongitud();
    else
        longitud = 0.0f;

    return convertview;}
```

So, how can I get a smooth scrolling? Adding a asyntask? with asynctask I couldn't get a good performance. Neither with scrolllistener. How can I achieve a good development to get a smooth scroll?

Thank you in advanced.

**UPDATE**

My layout xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/fotoLayout"
android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/fotoParking"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imagen" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fotoParking"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Fecha: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Ciudad: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Calle: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtFecha"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCiudad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:maxLines="1" 
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCalle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:maxLines="1" 
    android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What layout are you using in your xml? Sometimes relative layout slows scrolling a bit.

Comment: It might be the image loading but I suggest profiling or at least timing your method calls to see what is actually taking a long time.

Comment: I've posted the layout I'm using. I guess it's the image load that makes the scroll not be smooth but what's the better solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getview method should not do any heavy processes on UI thread for smoothly scrollable listview.

Instead of fetching bitmap and displaying it GetView method, use **Universal Image Loader** [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to display images.